# Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html ide intelij Idea (maven,spring) не могу подключить сторонний файл

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-mvc, maven

Учусь работать на java хотел подключить стили, сделал как было показанно в туториале, но не получилось..
подключил в index.mustachу как обычно в хэдере ссылкой

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css"  >
```

указал путь вот так

```
package com.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}
```

}

static лежит в resources там же лежит templates и сам файл index.mustache

я что-то не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибся в маршруте, а так все правильно